# How to add border radius on Quasar table

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm trying to create a table with header like this

[image: table's header]

I try with this code, but no luck

```
    <q-table binary-state-sort
      table-header-class="text-white bg-44b2b8 rounded"
      :data="this.$store.state.apiKeyList"
      :columns="columns"
      :filter="filter"
      row-key="name"
      flat
    >
      <template v-slot:top>
        <q-input debounce="300" color="primary" v-model="filter">
          <template v-slot:prepend>
            <q-icon name="search" />
          </template>
        </q-input>
      </template>
    </q-table>
```

in css file:

```
.rounded {
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}
```

any clue to achieve the rounded header?

Comment: What about creating your own header and using the header slot of q-table to add it

Comment: Built-in styling vars may apply. Search for _radius_ https://quasar.dev/style/sass-scss-variables#customizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `table-header-class` to just class for `rounded` class and it works

codepen - https://codepen.io/Pratik__007/pen/QWNEwmp